# Can not find system.web.http

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

I have to add a `System.Web.Http` assembly reference because I added the `HttpConfiguration` class to my unit test class library project.

When I browse the Add reference dialog I can not find the `System.Web.Http`assembly.

The class library project has the .Net 4.5.1 Framework targeted.

Comment: It could be that you have to install MVC. Have tried using nuget?

Comment: I solved it. I had to install web api core first which has system.web.http included. :)

Answer (score 127):

In order to get the `System.Web.Http` you will need to install a NuGet package in the NuGet command line:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core/

Comment: that drove me crazy.... I must be thinking wrong but anything that starts with the namespace "System" seems like it shouldnt have to be installed via a nuget package.

Comment: When working with multiple solutions / projects, be sure to select the right solution in the package manager console to install the package to; this had me confused for a bit.

Comment: I had to use Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost.

Comment: I had to use `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client -Version 5.2.7` instead (.Client instead of .Core). I had .Core 5.2.7 already, but I was still getting the error. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/

Comment: freakin' stupid that the namespace isn't the same as the package name.

Comment: I added the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client nuget package

Comment: Weird that this isn't considered a dependency.

Answer (score 7):

I've had multiple errors regarding missing references such as "system.web.http" or "system.web.razor" in my project. Even though I do have all the references installed through nuget.

What worked for me was to install a standalone version of AspNetMVC4, even though Visual Studio 2014 installed that as well. Apparently it was missing some references in Windows. I've installed this from the Microsoft website, and all went well afterwards.

Hope this helps someone. It drove me crazy for like 2 days, nothing regarding nuget worked for me, I've deleted and reinstalled the references a couple times, did everything I've found in multiple posts on stackoverflow, nothing worked.

Url for mvc4 standalone setup from microsoft: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30683

Comment: My variant for VS 2017: use NuGet and downgrade a version of Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core; then re-install the right version.  Accept Licenses (which is probably what was needed).  Important: close and reopen visual studio.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For every one haveing this problem. Remember that you might have a downgraded version of based on your framework. Try look on your packagde folder what version you have. Then upade that version. Dont use Update-Package it will update all version with no respect to the framework your running at all.

Answer (score 0):

It was solved by commenting out the "bindingRedirect" part.

bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0"/