# System.Web.Http fails with not found error when upgrading Microsoft.Azure.Devices sdk version

Tags: .net, azure-iot-hub, .net-standard-2.0, system.web.http

I'm essentially facing the same issue as here: [Can not find system.web.http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940369/can-not-find-system-web-http) but this ONLY occurs when I bump up my Microsoft.Azure.Devices version from 1.5.2 to 1.33.0. I have tested this repeatedly and determined that the two are indeed related. I can't find any other instances of people mentioning this online. The .csproj file I am using is netstandard2.0

Can anyone tell me what they think could be the reason this is happening so I can note it down for reference?

Comment: could you share the sample code you used just for testing? I think code is not a problem in your issues. just a reference please share your code .Thank you.

Comment: If you can create a minimal reproducible sample, we can help you.

Comment: @m341 `Microsoft.Azure.Devices` maximum version is  `1.39.0` for this [reference](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Devices#:~:text=Microsoft.%20Azure.%20Devices%201.39.0%20Prefix%20Reserved.NET%205.0.NET%20Core,available.%20See%20the%20version%20list%20below%20for%20details) and it supports `2.0`

Comment: The issue goes away when I install package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core' version 5.2.7 in addition to 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client' version 5.2.7 but not optimal as I don't want introduce a .core sdk into .net standard if anyone needs a workaround. My plan is to axe out System.Web.Http completely.

Comment: @Sampath we can't use the latest version because it has removed certain methods our setup requires. thanks

Comment: @Sampath please reread the above, I have listed a workaround for those who need help and stated what my plan is regarding this. There is no issue to be fixed anymore, thanks

Comment: @m341 Please post your answer so it helps others

Answer (score 0):

Converting the comments as the answer for the benefit of community and posting on behalf of OP:

According to the comments by m341 the problem of `Microsoft.Azure.Devices` got resloved by
installing `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` nuget package with version 5.2.7 in addition to `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` version 5.2.7 .

[image]

[image]